# Compare values from 2 array PHP

Tags: php

I need to compare 2 values from 2 array.

I figured it out but the problem is that i need to do a comparasion between qty based on a unique id.

array 1 is from a csv:

```
prod_id,qty
1,1
2,3
3,1
4,3
5,1
```

array 2 is from database:

```
id,prod_id,qty
1,1,5
2,2,3
3,4,1
4,4,1
5,5,1
```

so now i have to compare this 2 arrays and get the difference between quantity,
for example:

id 1 has in database 5 qty and in csv 1 so it result +4
id 3 has no value in database and in csv has 1 so it result -1

i have tried with:

```
foreach($array1 as $csv) {
            $id[] = $csv['id'];
            $data[$csv['id']] = $csv['qty'];

        }

        foreach($array2 as $db) {

                $data[$db['id']] = $db['totalQty'];

        }
```

but it give me the result from database and result from csv.

Is there another way to compare the quantity and get only the differences ?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: _id 3 has no value in database_. `id` 3 has `value=1` in database

Comment: Hi, yes, id from csv is prod_id in database. Thx

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit more? I'm still confused with 3,4,1 and 4,4,1 in database (your 3rd and 4th id)...

Comment: ia it how your data is represented in PHP? 

$array1 = array(
    array(1, 1), 
    array(2, 3),
    array(3, 1),
    array(4, 3),
    array(5, 1)
);

$array2 = array(
  array(1,1,5),
  array(2,2,3),
  array(3,4,1),
  array(4,4,1),
  array(5,5,1)
);

Comment: I have commented on Nightwhistle answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i got this correctly...

```
<?php

$csv = array(
    0 => array('prod_id'=>1,'qty'=>1),
    1 => array('prod_id'=>2,'qty'=>3),
    2 => array('prod_id'=>3,'qty'=>1),
    3 => array('prod_id'=>4,'qty'=>3),
    4 => array('prod_id'=>5,'qty'=>1)
);

$data = array(
    0 => array('id'=>1,'prod_id'=>1,'qty'=>5),
    1 => array('id'=>2,'prod_id'=>2,'qty'=>3),
    2 => array('id'=>3,'prod_id'=>4,'qty'=>1),
    3 => array('id'=>4,'prod_id'=>4,'qty'=>1),
    4 => array('id'=>5,'prod_id'=>5,'qty'=>1),
    5 => array('id'=>6,'prod_id'=>6,'qty'=>7)
);

$result = array();


foreach ($data as $a=>$b) {
        $data_id = $b['id'];
        $data_prod_id = $b['prod_id'];
        $data_qty = $b['qty'];
        $in_csv = false;

    foreach ($csv as $k=>$v) {
        $csv_prod_id = $v['prod_id'];
        $csv_qty = $v['qty'];

        if ($data_prod_id == $csv_prod_id && $data_id == $csv_prod_id) {
            $result[$data_id] = $data_qty - $csv_qty;
        }

        if ($data_id != $data_prod_id) {
            $result[$data_id] = 0 - $csv_qty;
            break;
        }

        if ($data_prod_id == $csv_prod_id) {
            $in_csv = true;
        }

        if (!$in_csv) {
            $result[$data_id] = $data_qty;
        }

    }

}

foreach ($result as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v != 0) {
        echo "ID $k has changed : $v  <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nightwhistle, yes it sort out, but i have now a little issue, if i have for example on database id 6 prod_id 6 and prod_id is not in CSV the prod_id 6 will not be showing, is there a way to get also the prod_id 6 if it doesn't exist in CSV ? is the same think as CSV is missing prod_id 3 in database. Thanks a lot.